# RotateLeft operation on a 32 bit Integer

Tags: java, rotation, bit-manipulation, bit

I have been working on different projects for my Computer Organization class and we have been working on BitWise operations. Our current task is writing a homemade 'rotateLeft' method for java.

While java already has on, by using Integer.rotateLeft, my current task is writing one to work with this program.

Note: The int variables equal these bit strings

x1 = 3 = 00000000000000000000000000000011
x2 = -11= 1111111111111111111111111111110101

My current program is:

```
public class Demo
 {
     public static void main(String[]args)
    {
         int x1=3, x2=-11;
         System.out.print("x1:            ");
         BitWise.printbit(x1);
         System.out.print("rotateLeft(x1,2):  ");
         BitWise.printbit(rotateLeft(x1,2));
         System.out.print("x2:            ");
         BitWise.printbit(x2);
         System.out.print("rotateLeft(x2,2):  ");
          BitWise.printbit(rotateLeft(x2,2));
        }
         public static int rotateLeft(int i, int distance)
         {
           int mask= i>>distance;
          return mask;

          }
       }
```

This operation works for the x1 bit pattern, however, it merely shifts the bits, not actually rotates them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do say it is not rotating? can you share the expected o/p and the original output details?

Comment: @MSD  the current set up I have merely shifts the bits. Which would work for the first bit string. However not the second one since the first two bits that I'm shifting out become zeros on the other end. I'm trying to come up with a way in which it rotates the bits being shifted out back on the other end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x1 = 3;
  int x2 = -11;

  int x1IntegerRotated = Integer.rotateLeft(x1, 2);
  int x1SelfRotated = rotateLeft(x1, 2);
  System.out.printf("x1 = %d(%s)%n",               x1,               printIntBitwise(x1));
  System.out.printf("x1IntegerRotated = %d(%s)%n", x1IntegerRotated, printIntBitwise(x1IntegerRotated));
  System.out.printf("x1SelfRotated = %d(%s)%n",    x1SelfRotated,    printIntBitwise(x1SelfRotated));

  System.out.println();

  int x2IntegerRotated = Integer.rotateLeft(x2, 2);
  int x2SelfRotated = rotateLeft(x2, 2);
  System.out.printf("x2 = %d(%s)%n",               x2,               printIntBitwise(x2));
  System.out.printf("x2IntegerRotated = %d(%s)%n", x2IntegerRotated, printIntBitwise(x2IntegerRotated));
  System.out.printf("x2SelfRotated = %d(%s)%n",    x2SelfRotated,    printIntBitwise(x2SelfRotated));
}

private static int rotateLeft(int value, int distance) {
  int mask = (1 << distance) - 1;
  int leftPart = (value << distance) & (~mask);
  int rightPart = (value >> (32 - distance)) & (mask);

  int result = leftPart | rightPart;

  return result;
}

private static String printIntBitwise(int a) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for(int i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
    sb.append(Math.abs((a & (1 << (32 - i))) >> (32 - i)));
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: You can leave out the masks if you use `>>>` (for the left shift you don't need it now either)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have figured out a way of doing this:

```
//This is a helper function; it returns an int where the leftmost num bits are 1 and the rest are 0
static int get1s(int num) {
    int buf = 0;
    for (int i = 31; i>31-num;i--) {
        buf += 1 << i;
    }
    return buf;
}

static int rotateLeft(int i, int distance) {
    int end = i & get1s(distance);
    int mov = end >>> 32 - distance;
    int shift = i << distance;
    return shift + mov;
}
```

Basically, the way that this works, line by line, is as follows:

- Set `end` equal to just the leftmost `distance` bits, without actually shifting it.
- Set `mov` equal to `end` shifted enough to make it the rightmost `distance` bits.
- Set `shift` equal to the shifted value.
- Return `shift` plus `mov`, thereby placing what were once the leftmost bits at the right.

If you want to see how this works in more detail, you can print the results after each step:

```
static int rotateLeftWithPrint(int i, int distance) {
    int end = i & get1s(distance);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(end));
    int mov = end >>> 32 - distance;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(mov));
    int shift = i << distance;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(shift));

    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(shift+mov));
    return shift + mov;
}
```

(**NOTE**) `Integer.toBinaryString` does *not* show leading zeroes, so that's why it won't always print `String`s of the same length.

**EDIT** - Thought this might be useful, you can add binary literals by placing `0b` before the digits; `3` is equivalent to `0b00000000000000000000000000000011`.